# How to ignore extra fields for fmt.Sprintf

Tags: go

I have a Golang program that reads a string parameter from command line and passes it to the fmt.Sprintf function. Let's say tmp_str is the target string from command line.

```
package main

import "fmt"

func main() {
    tmp_str := "hello %s"
    str := fmt.Sprintf(tmp_str, "world")
    fmt.Println(str)
}
```

In some cases, the program will pass a completed string like "Hello Friends", instead of a string template.. The program would panic and return:

> Hello Friends%!(EXTRA string=world)

So, how to ignore the extra fields for fmt.Sprintf?

Comment: I'm not sure if Go's fmt library has the same security issues as C but to be on the safe side you should never use format strings from untrusted sources. In C this leads to information leaks, like printing out sensitive stack data and even data overwrite and code execution.

Comment: @ZanLynx thanks for the update. I just simplified the question. The program is not exposed to others for sure.

Comment: @Zan Lynx There are no such security concerns in Go's fmt library and elsewhere in regular Go code. Which doesn't imply it's a great idea to juggle with format strings at will.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Yes you can do it, by slicing the arguments you pass to the variadic `Sprintf` function:

```
func TruncatingSprintf(str string, args ...interface{}) (string, error) {
    n := strings.Count(str, "%s")
    if n > len(args) {
        return "", errors.New("Unexpected string:" + str)
    }
    return fmt.Sprintf(str, args[:n]...), nil
}

func main() {
    tmp_str := "hello %s %s %s"         // don't hesitate to add many %s here
    str, err := TruncatingSprintf(tmp_str, "world") // or many arguments here
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println(err)
        return
    }
    fmt.Println(str)
}
```

[**Demonstration 1**](https://play.golang.org/p/NSFFzgLC7B)

[**Demonstration 2**](https://play.golang.org/p/Ib2ULyAqCp) (a different version outputting even when there's more %s than arguments)

But you don't usually use dynamic formatted strings, this isn't secure and if you want to accept *any* string, you should also adapt this code to no choke on `%%s`. If you venture this far, then you should probably have a look at [templates](https://golang.org/pkg/text/template/) (which would let you use named strings, and thus the missing one wouldn't have to be the last one).

Comment: Great answer. Added a bit of error handling that OP can expand on: https://play.golang.org/p/NSFFzgLC7B

Comment: @william.taylor.09 good idea. I took your error handling and added it into the answer so that nobody would miss it. But note that having more %s than arguments could be considered *OK* (there's just some "MISSING")

Comment: Adding an indexed placeholder helps: `fmt.Sprintf("Hello"+"%[2]s", "World", "")`

Answer (score 10):

In this particular case, you could require the command line users to always supply a %s verb, and explain they can truncate the string to zero length:

```
Hello Friends%.0s
```

or even shorter:

```
Hello Friends%.s
```

The output is plain:

> Hello Friends

Comment: In my particular case, this was perfect. Simple and straightforward.

Comment: This worked perfectly for me as well. I also noticed that you can use "%.T" to ignore any data type (not just strings!). For example, `fmt.Printf("arg1=%s, arg2=%.T, arg3=%.T, arg4=%.T, arg=%s", "arg1", 2.123, true, "arg4", "arg5")` => "arg1=arg1, arg2=, arg3=, arg4=, arg=arg5" (see: https://play.golang.org/p/m0ahZ7ofAH_f and https://golang.org/pkg/fmt/). With this approach, however, there is a "Printf format %.T has unrecognized flag ." error from Go vet which I haven't explained yet. Thanks Stein and Roshambo! :)

Answer (score 4):

I agree with [Volker's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35043276/102852), but you could check your input string:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "strings"
)

func main() {
    tmp_str := "hello %s"

    res := tmp_str
    if strings.Count(tmp_str, "%s") == 1 {
        res = fmt.Sprintf(tmp_str, "world")
    }
    fmt.Println(res)
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I am kinda new to Golang. I think your answer is very inspiring!

Answer (score 0):

I use this one (which can probably be expanded on)

```
Sprintf("Hello"+"%[2]s", "World", "")
Sprintf("Hello %s"+"%[2]s", "World", "")
```

Answer (score -7):

You cannot do this.

You have to find a different solution.

Comment: This is a comment, not an answer. Why is this upvoted?

Comment: The (original) question was about how to make `fmt.Printf` ignore extra arguments and that cannot be done. The different solution is to preprocess you arguments but that's programming 101 and has nothing to do with `fmt.Printf`.