# How to wrap FPrintf in Go?

Tags: go, printf

I am trying to write a functional that wraps FPrintf however I keep getting weird characters out.

Here is an reproducer

https://play.golang.org/p/yZgNnpovEa

The idea is to be able to have a conditional Printf which I can test the output (Thus use of FPrintf so I can test the output towards the input). Is there any way to get around this?

I have seen [How to ignore extra fields for fmt.Sprintf](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35043202/how-to-ignore-extra-fields-for-fmt-sprintf) but all answers there assume the user is expecting only %s while in my case I want to be as flexible as Printf and the only other one is downvoted.

Is this just not possible and can anybody give a reasonable explanation why?

Comment: The answer is the same as the question you linked, you're missing the `...` to expand the `params` slice.

Comment: See also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23723955/how-can-i-pass-a-slice-as-a-variadic-input

Comment: Wow I should go back to programming school. Thank you. Ofc I need to expand the params

Answer (score 0):

The problem is you actually send an empty slice to `fmt.Fprintf`.
Additional check of params' length should fix the problem.

```
func (p ConditionalPrinter) printF(s string, params ...interface{}) {
    if p.print {
        if len(params) == 0 {
            fmt.Fprintf(p.writer, s)
        } else {
            fmt.Fprintf(p.writer, s, params)
        }
    }
}
```

Or this:

```
func (p ConditionalPrinter) printF(s string, params ...interface{}) {
    switch {        
    case !p.print:
        return
    case len(params) == 0:
        fmt.Fprintf(p.writer, s)
    default:
        fmt.Fprintf(p.writer, s, params)
    }
}
```

See [Playground link](https://play.golang.org/p/28mR9VqsVq)

Comment: This is not quite right. You should use `FPrintF(p.writer, s, params...)` irrespectively of whether it's empty or not. And then you don't need to check for the length because the trailnig `...` applies the slice and doesn't pass it as a normal argument.